# Google Login For Phonegap

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, sencha-touch, google-signin, hello.js

After the authentication page does not return the redirect url and showing 404 error. I need the run project in mobile . I am building with phonegap but mobile does not have localhost. how to define local file to redirect_uri ?

Returns This url after

> http:// localhost /cevap/redirect.html?state=%7B%22client_id%22:%2275055614045-a999nkehht0jk3i46548qg32imu0toqg.apps.googleusercontent.com%22,%22network%22:%22google%22,%22display%22:%22popup%22,%22callback%22:%22_hellojs_8ws7jbej%22,%22state%22:%22%22,%22oauth_proxy%22:%22https://auth-server.herokuapp.com/proxy%22,%22scope%22:%22friends,basic%22,%22oauth%22:%7B%22version%22:2,%22auth%22:%22https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth%22,%22grant%22:%22https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token%22%7D%7D&code=4/x9MedwZ8NJN6qUgq2rXAVaBtFuOk.QpP5N0crfbAbYFZr95uygvVVqe1rjwI&authuser=0&num_sessions=1&hd=veriyazilim.com.tr&session_state=f715c83530f60300552e4920948401332014eeea..224b&prompt=none

[image]

```
 hello.init({
            google : '75055614045-a999nkehht0jk3i46548qg32imu0toqg.apps.googleusercontent.com'
        }, {
               redirect_uri : 'http://localhost/cevap/redirect.html',
            response_type:'code',
            scope:'friends'

        });
```

I created Client ID for web application in google .

[image]

This is my folder directionary :

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem does not in url.

inappbrowser doesnt load to project. I changed config.xml plugin to this and inappbrowser loaded and problem fixed.

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For developing in a desktop browser:

A dev domain is required which matches the domain you defined as a callback url when registering your app - define this callback url in redirect_uri, and ensure it points a document containing `./hello.js`.

in your case this file would be located at `http:// localhost /cevap/redirect.html`

For phonegap this isn't the case as apps are run as "file://path/to/installed/apps/myproject" or something. But phonegap apps can watch the URL of popup windows it intitiates, and thats exactly how hello.js works to extract the access_token from the popup windows querystring. in this case there is no need for the redirect_uri to be a valid path, but for a better user experience i would have it point to a web resource which can display something like a spinning wheel.

Comment: I found the problem. Actually problem not in url.  Problem in config.xml

inappbrowser does not loading.